# Difference between tableofcontents and listoffigures internal codes

Tags: macros, document-classes

In standard classes `book.cls` and `report.cls` we find

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

and

```
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

In article.cls

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

and

```
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \section*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    }
```

and in documentation we read

> The code for `\@mkboth` is placed inside the heading to avoid any
>   influence on vertical spacing after the heading (in some cases). For
>   other commands, such as `\listoffigures` below this has been changed
>   from the LATEX2.09 version as it will produce a serious bug if used in
>   two-column mode (see, pr/3285). However `\tableofcontents` is always
>   typeset in one-column mode in these classes, therefore the somewhat
>   inconsistent setting has been retained for compatibility reasons.

**Question**
Can any one please explain a bit this paragraph, in particular **in some cases** (so if there is an example)

and **However  `\tableofcontents` is always typeset in one-column**

---

**Update - Main questions**

1. Why `\@mkboth` is placed inside the heading for `\tableofcontents`?
2. Why the two codes `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures` are differents?

**Answers** (what i understand)

> `\@mkboth` is placed inside the heading to avoid any influence on
>   vertical spacing after the heading (in some cases)

OK I can see the point here, but then the 2nd question come: why we don't do same for `\listoffigures`?

> For other commands, such as `\listoffigures` below this has been changed
>   from the LATEX2.09 version as it will produce a serious bug if used in
>   two-column mode (see, pr/3285).

Here I can't see! and next lines confuse me more.

Comment: I can't see any difference regarding one-column or two-column.

Comment: `\@mkboth` is no fixed command actually. Depending on page style it is `\markboth` or a `\@gobbletwo` etc, via `\let`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks, I am trying to understand why the codes are differents and documentation confuse me more (well it's my english)

Comment: Perhaps you should ask David Carlisle or Joseph Wright in chat, they should know more on this. I think it's some kind of a relict

Comment: http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3285

Comment: Doesn't the `in some cases` mean cases where it is set in two column mode? It could be clearer, though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there an answer to that question?

Comment: @Johannes_B i will add one soon

Comment: @Johannes_B the answer is basically [here](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3984)

Comment: @touhami I think an answer here would be even better :-) Or should we ping Frank?

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you, as i said i'll add an answer. Of course it's better from Frank, but let's try my answer first (it's all about understanding)